# Casting IOrderedEnumerable to ICollection

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I want to sort the order of some random integers before inserting into my database.

```
if (integerList.Direction.Equals("ascending")) {
    integerList.Integers = integerList.Integers.OrderBy(i => i.IntegerValue);
} else {
    integerList.Integers = integerList.Integers.OrderByDescending(i => i.IntegerValue);
}
```

orderby and orderbydescending seem to convert the integers from ICollection in my class to IOrderedEnumerable. Can anybody suggest how to cast the sorted integers?

Comment: generally databases are better at sorting data than code is, so in many cases you will be better just dumping the data in what ever order you have it into the database and then placing the order statement on your select queries

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ToList()
```

Will create a List for your, if I remember correctly that inherits from Collection.

Comment: Or `ToArray()`. Which is better depends how you are going to use the collection.

Comment: Also `ToDictionary()`, if that floats your boat.

Comment: ToList would create another copy, what is the best way to do it without creating additional copy?

Answer (score 0):

From your question I assume that the `Integers` property is of type `ICollection<int>`. Add `ToList()` or `ToArray()` to convert the result into a `List<int>` or an `int[]` (both implement `ICollection`).

Since you can not be sure that the database stores the values in the order in which they are added it does not make sense to order them before adding to the database. Instead you should add an index to the respective field and use ORDER BY on that field to get ordered values back.